# How to Justify the text in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I am Using asp.net and i have the following Data :

> Users are prohibited from posting or transmitting any unlawful, threatening,libelous, defamatory, obscene, scandalous, inflammatory, abusive, hateful,                          pornographic, or profane material, or any material that could constitute or encourage  conduct that would be considered a criminal offense, give rise to civil liability, or                                                       otherwise violate any law. We reserve the right, in our sole and absolute discretion, to terminate, suspend or restrict your access to this Site, unilaterally and without notice, in the event you violate any of the terms of this Agreement. In addition, if asked to do so, you agree that you will not attempt to access this Site. We also reserve any and all remedies at law or equity in connection with any violation of this Agreement. You agree, at your own expense, to indemnify, defend and hold the Company (and its subsidiaries, affiliates, officers, directors, agents, employees and third parties providing content) harmless from and against any claim or demand and all losses incurred related to the use of the Site.
>
> We use a diverse range of information, text, photographs, designs, graphics, images, sound and video recordings, animation, content, advertisement and other materials and effects (collectively "Materials") for the search services on the Media. We provide the Material through the Media FOR YOUR PERSONAL AND NON-COMMERCIAL USE ONLY.

I have tried this but the result is the text are align to left. I want to justify the text. Is there any attribute for justifying the text in asp.net using css? Please help.

Comment: How you want you text to be shown, and what have you tried tell us

Comment: you are displaying it in html tags or asp label,literal tags..

Comment: Yes sir I am trying to show it by using asp tags like p, div etc. and i have tried the style properties of div

Comment: p,div are not asp tags.they are html generic controls..simply give p{text-align:justify;}...It will work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using **`div`** or **`p`** tags then use `inline style` for them as shown

```
<div style="text-align:justify;">Users are prohibited from posting or transmitting any unlawful, threatening,libelous, defamatory, obscene, scandalous, inflammatory, abusive, hateful,                          pornographic, or profane material, or any material that could constitute or encourage  conduct that would be considered a criminal offense, give rise to civil liability, or                                                       otherwise violate any law. We reserve the right, in our sole and absolute discretion, to terminate, suspend or restrict your access to this Site, unilaterally and without notice, in the event you violate any of the terms of this Agreement. In addition, if asked to do so, you agree that you will not attempt to access this Site. We also reserve any and all remedies at law or equity in connection with any violation of this Agreement. You agree, at your own expense, to indemnify, defend and hold the Company (and its subsidiaries, affiliates, officers, directors, agents, employees and third parties providing content) harmless from and against any claim or demand and all losses incurred related to the use of the Site.
  We use a diverse range of information, text, photographs, designs, graphics, images, sound and video recordings, animation, content, advertisement and other materials and effects (collectively "Materials") for the search services on the Media. We provide the Material through the Media FOR YOUR PERSONAL AND NON-COMMERCIAL USE ONLY.</div>
```

Or else try to add a stylesheet to your application and try to use the style as shown

```
.mytext{
text-align:justify;
}
```

and in your webpage you can use it as shown

```
<div style="mytext">your text goes here...</div>
```

Comment: inline style... yuck.

Comment: @RaúlRoa-Updated with the styling too.

Comment: @coder, inline styling is not preferred. B.T.W., your answer also has `text align`. Lolz, please update it. We're even now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `<p style="text-align:justify;">...</p>` in your HTML. Better to define style elements in CSS

HTML

```
<p class="justified">...</p>
```

CSS

```
.justified {
    text-align: justify;
}
```

If you are using `Label`, you may set the `HorizontalAlign` property:

```
<asp:Label HorizontalAlign="Justify" runat="server">
    Some Content
</asp:Label>
```

Comment: @theghostofc-It's not text align it's text-align

Comment: @coder, thanks for pointing that out. I don't know how I missed that out. Silly me! Have updated now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried most suggestions and couldn't get it to work (gridview), so added a css class...

```
   .LabelFormat
    {
             padding-bottom:4px
    }
```

lame but it worked.